# How to add a value to request HEAD

Tags: dart, dart-html

When calling GET method, user defined value is not added to HEAD

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
    var url = 'https://dev";
    var res = await http.get(
         url, 
         headers: {'X-Api-Key': 'xxxxxx'},
        );
    print(res.body);
}
```

### I expect the output of

```
Host: a.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-api-key
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Origin: http://localhost:8080
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
X-Api-Key: xxxxxx
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: Trailers
```

(firefox request header)

### but the actual output is

```
Host: a.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-api-key
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Origin: http://localhost:8080
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

(firefox request header)

Comment: Are you sure that your API send back the pikey?